# How to add group in custom registration form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, registration, create

In the frontend signup, how to add a group in customer registration form in Magento 2.2.2

See the screenshot : 
https://prnt.sc/jsuu4a

I have set the default group to be Please select in the backend: 
`Stores > configuration > customers > customers configuration > Default Group` to be Please Select

But it didn't show in the frontend.

Comment: You have to add it by hard code and saved by observer after customer save

Comment: The customer group is now showing in the frontend. See the screenshot : https://prnt.sc/jtia5m  but the user cannot create an account. The error is showing i.e  "Group" is a required value. And i have set the default group to be https://prnt.sc/jtiann